# Hadoop YARN Cluster Performance Tuning

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

[image]

I'll like to know a few parameters to speed up Spark jobs on my YARN cluster.

I have the following Spark/YARN configs in place, but I'm not happy with the speed of execution. I have a lot of unused vcores and memory.

Spark configs:

```
- spark.yarn.am.cores = 2
- spark.executor.memory = 5g
- spark.executor.cores = 8
```

YARN configs:

```
- yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb = 31744
- yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores = 15
- yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb = 31744
```

From the image,

1. on node 3 & 5, why usage of 6gb out of 2gb.
2. Memory on node 1,2,4,5,6 are not used at all

Moreso, I want to be able to spin up more containers per node in the cluster.

Help much appreciated.

Comment: Your current application asking for just 3 containers from YARN. Try to increase the number of spark executors using --num-executors 3, adjusting the executor memory and cores may be also useful. Be aware of the fact that the following steps should increase resource utilisation, but you need understand how Spark works to tune the performance of your application.

Answer (score 1):

Adding this spark conf, did the trick:

```
spark.executor.instances = 6
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To improve Spark Jobs on Yarn, you can use the following arguments:

**spark.executor.instances**: it creates several executors (actually JVMs) in order to improve performs such as drecute said.

```
spark.executor.instances = 6
```

**spark.executor.cores:** Moreover, Spark is multithread-compliant. It means that for every executor you've defined, spark can process several actions simultaneously on this executor. To you use:

```
spark.executor.cores = $int
```

**caching in memory**: Finally, it is possible to cache data in memory in order to improve performs. By using this, you can expect divide latency time between 5 times and 20 times. To use this mode, refer to following arguments:

```
spark.driver.memory
spark.executor.memory
spark.driver.memory
spark.yarn.memoryOverhead
spark.yarn.driver.memoryOverhead
```

Here is a tutorial from Cloudera which explains how to tune your spark jobs and how to cache data in memory:

http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/03/how-to-tune-your-apache-spark-jobs-part-2/